# Using COM objects from Dotnet CLI

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

Is it possible to use COM objects from Dotnet CLI applications?

How would a COM object be referenced from the app, i.e. what would the project.json look like?

A concrete example would be:
create a blank project via *dotnet new* and modify it such that it starts MS Word via its COM interface.

It is obvious that this will only work on Windows but it would be nice to be able to do this to integrate old code.
I already found out how to use a native DLL by wrapping it into a nuget package, for details see https://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/11/10/using-native-libraries-in-asp-net-5/
But COM objects are accessed globally via the registry. I could create an interop assembly but I don't know how to reference that from my project.
Another possibility would probably be to write a native DLL wrapper around the COM object and use that via a nuget package but that seems really less than optimal.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Actually I gave up on trying this last year because ASP.NET Core underwent too many changes at that time. Now we have official releases and the return to the msbuild project system is done so I think it would be  worthwile to again have a look at it but I have not checked it yet.